# How to Re-Write the graph in a Graphview without getting the extra line?

Tags: android, android-graphview, livegraph

I'm trying to plot the value in GraphView and for 2nd time i'm trying plot the another set of data in the same graphview but I'm getting some extra unwanted line in the graphview.

in the above picture Red colored marked line is the extra line I'm getting while plotting the graph.

I'm using com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView

Here is my sample code , when ever i click on OK button it will start plotting the graph.

public class ABIModeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> mSeries2;
private double graph2LastXValue = 5d;
static GraphView graph2;
Context context;
Button okbutton;
CountDownTimer cTimer = null;
int i=0;
int[] BP_Data=new int[]{115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,115,113,105,76,36,7,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,33,73,105,112,114,113,84,32,22,5,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,8,37,76,95,112,111,90,51,12,2,0,0,0,0,2,21,59,83,105,113,112,105,62,48,17,2,7,33,73,105,112,114,113,84,32,22,5,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,8,37,76,95,112,111,90,51,12,2,0,2,21,59,83,105,113,112,105,62,48,17,2,2,21,59,83,105,113,112,105,62,48,17,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_abimode);

    //I'm using Timer to simulate the live data graph which I'm getting in my actual device.
    //Timer is used only for simulation of live data
    cTimer = new CountDownTimer(100000, 20) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            graph2LastXValue += 1d;
            drawgraph(graph2LastXValue,BP_Data[i]);
            i++;
            if(i==180){
                cTimer.cancel();//Stop the live graph plotting when it reached the end of data
                i=0;
            }
        }
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    };

    okbutton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
    okbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            cTimer.start();// to start plotting the graph data with the timer
        }
    });
    //Actuall graph realted code starting
    graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph2);
    mSeries2 = new LineGraphSeries<>();
    mSeries2.setThickness(3);
    graph2.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph2.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph2.getViewport().setMinX(0);
    graph2.getViewport().setMaxX(200);
    graph2.getViewport().setMinY(0);
    graph2.getViewport().setMaxY(251);
    graph2.getGridLabelRenderer().setTextSize(0);
    graph2.getViewport().setScrollable(true); // enables horizontal scrolling
    graph2.getViewport().setScrollableY(true); // enables vertical scrolling
    graph2.getViewport().setDrawBorder(false);
    graph2.getViewport().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    graph2.addSeries(mSeries2);
    context = this;
}

public void drawgraph(Double graphvalue,int incrementValue)//plotting the value in the graph
{
    mSeries2.appendData(new DataPoint(graphvalue, incrementValue), true, 200);
}
```

}

[image: this red colored marked line is the thing i dont want.]

Comment: Please add some sample code of what you wrote so people can help you better. I believe you need to create a new series or reset it to prevent this unwanted effect.

Comment: Hai,
Thank you for your Reply , I have updated my code
i tried to reset but i didn't work. it meant i cant able to plot the graph after resetting.

Comment: I tested your code and I am not seeing the line you just explained. You have a line y values valued at 150 and then the sinusoidal values which matches BP_Data array data.

Comment: actually its a stored data, but in above picture is live data from BP modules.
if you press ok button two/three time you can see the previous graph also , i need fresh graph every time when i press ok button.i have updated my picture for sample.

Comment: I see. I believe I found what you were looking for. Check my answer and let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Thank you, You solved my problem.

Comment: Hai I'm getting another problem now, i have updated my question can you check it?

Comment: Hi, happy it resolved your problem! Can you please create ask another question and provide a link to it here? I will be more than happy to help.

Comment: Thank you, here is the link for my next post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323632/while-writing-data-to-the-graph-in-a-graphview-getting-some-the-extra-line-how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a newly drawn graph everytime you press the button, you need to add the following change to your onTick method:

```
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    graph2LastXValue += 1d;
    if (i == 0) {
        mSeries2.resetData(new DataPoint[]{new DataPoint(graph2LastXValue, BP_Data[i])});
    }
    drawgraph(graph2LastXValue, BP_Data[i]);
    i++;
    if (i == 180) {
        cTimer.cancel();//Stop the live graph plotting when it reached the end of data
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

This will reset your graph every time the value of i has been reset earlier and gives you the desired result.